# when is non homogeneous system consistent?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the condition for non homogeneous system to be consistent ( single solution or infinite)?

I don't know a condition for any solution, when the rank of the matrix equals to the original number of the rows it is a single solution I think

Answer (score 1):

A system $Av=b$ is consistent iff $b \in \text{Col}(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

As James S. Cook answered, the mathematical definition of it would be when b lies in the Columnspace of $A$.

Alternately, I think what you were looking for is the [Rouche-Capelli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem) which basically states that a system of equations will be consistent if the rank of the augmented matrix equals the rank of $A$.

Comment: Since in general adding a column to a matrix increases its rank by $1$ or by $0$, and the latter if and only if the added column (already) lies in the space spanned by the other columns, the two statements given are equivalent.